# Mapping CSV using json file

Tags: python, json, csv, python-3.x, mapping

I have a csv file containing 3 columns,

```
Dick,25,Coder
John,23,Architect
Roony,20,Designer
Paras,40,Manager
```

How do I parse it using python against a json mapper which states which column is what like column 2 is Age, 3 is Occupation ?
Something like -

```
[
  "Person","Age", "Job"
]
```

Also, It would be great if the value of age as integer.
I have the following code till now -

```
import csv
import json

mapper = open('file.json')
csv_file = 'data.csv'
with open(self.csv_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        rdr = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='|')
        j = json.loads(mapper.read())
        for i in range(0, len(rdr)):
            row = rdr[i]
            mapped_r = j[i]
```

I want something like -

```
mapped = CSVMapper.MapObjects('data.csv', 'mapper.json')
print mapped[0].Age == 25 # age of Dick (1st element)
```

Is there a better way to approach the problem ?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Updated question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think https://github.com/samarjeet27/CSV-Mapper/ will suit your needs.
Install using

```
pip install csvmapper
```

Go through the examples from the repo. Maybe you can use it this way in your case -

mapper.json file -

```
[
   [
      { "name" : "Person" },
      { "name" : "Age", "type" : "int" }
      { "name" : "Job" }
   ]
]
```

and you can implement it as -

```
import csvmapper

mapper = csvmapper.JSONMapper('mapper.json')
parser = csvmapper.CSVParser('data.csv', mapper)

for item in parser.buildObject():
    print item.Job # Job of the item
    print "will be %d after 2 years" %(item.Age+2) # item.Age is an int
```

Hope this helped !